# Contours tuple must have length 2 or 3, otherwise OpenCV changed their cv2.findContours return signature yet again- find contour in a specific area

Tags: python, image, opencv, contour, imutils

```
cnts,_ = cv2.findContours(cv.rectangle(img3.copy(), (0,200) , (5000, 1150), (255,0,0), 2) ,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(rgb_img, cnts, -1, (0,255,0), 2)


conts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
c = max(conts, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

I'm trying to find the contours of two irregular edges in between the image. Else the rectangular actual edge of the image is being detected as contour max area. So i thought of using a rectangular area where I want it to exactly detect the edges.

Comment: what is the error? you might be using `imutils.grab_contours` wrong

Comment: and why are you drawing a rectangle?

Comment: this dude has some nerve... https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils/blob/9f740a53bcc2ed7eba2558afed8b4c17fd8a1d4c/imutils/convenience.py#L169 error by users of *his* library, blamed on OpenCV. he doesn't even check that it's actually a tuple. in this case it's not a tuple, it's the list of contours that got passed.

Comment: `cnts = cv2.findContours` `conts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)`

Comment: "So i thought of using a rectangular area where I want it to exactly detect the edges." -- this sounds more like you want to get a roi / slice of the image , not draw a rectangle into it

Comment: @miki I'm not trying to draw a rectangle. I want to use only that specific part of the pictures for finding contours.

Comment: @berak I'm not trying to draw a rectangle. I want to use only that specific part of the pictures for finding contours.

Comment: @Starcode1619 but you **are** drawing a rectangle. Use numpy slicing instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `imutils.grab_contours` wrong.

If you do the destructuring yourself, with `(cnts, *_) = cv.findContours(...)`, then **you don't need `imutils` at all**.

If you want to use `imutils` anyway, you need to pass it the entire tuple (2-tuple or 3-tuple) returned by `cv.findContours`, like so: `cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cv.findContours(...))`

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. But I'm not trying to draw a rectangle. I want to use only that specific part of the pictures for finding contours. What function can I use to do this?

Comment: I hope that was sufficiently addressed in the comments below the question ("numpy slicing").